# condition for homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

If $X $ and $Y $ are homeomorphic as topological spaces is there any necessary and sufficient condition for $X\setminus A$ and $Y \setminus B$ to be homeomorphic?$ A\subseteq X ,B\subseteq Y$

Comment: Are $A,B$ open sets?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ need not be homeomorphic themselves for this to be true. E.g. $A$ and $B$ can be any compact subspace of $X = Y = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, e.g.